# Why can't I change the domain when connecting to network shares in Windows 8?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, samba, domain

I have a computer running Windows 8.1 Pro. I also have Ubuntu 12.04.3 Server running within Hyper-V on the same machine. The Ubuntu server has Samba installed. Both the host and guest OS are connected to the workgroup `WORKGROUP`.

When I open up "Network" in Windows 8.1 and attempt to connect to the server (both by name and IP address), I receive the following prompt:

[image]

Entering the correct username and password for an account on the server fails. `/etc/samba/smb.conf` has the following share definitions set:

```
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
```

Comment: 192.168.1.109 is of the samba share? Then you can change the domain by entering 192.168.1.109\username and password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out that Samba requires that users manually be added before they can access their home directories over SMB. (The Ubuntu Server guide doesn't mention this anywhere.)

So this is what I needed to run:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a [username]
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to change the domain, prepend it to the username.  So type:

`mydomain\myusername`

Comment: That did indeed change the domain. However, I am still receiving access denied errors.

Comment: then you need to check your permissions

Comment: Which directories do I need to check? My home directory on the server is set to `0755`.

Comment: Unfortunately, linux permsissions is not my thing, however Im sure someone else knows the answer